# The number is not clearing up after submission even if other fields do clear up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have these fields that I want to clear up after submission. The other fields that were stated here do clear up except for the number. Why is this happening and how do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Textfield number:**

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
const handleNumber = (evt) => {
    const num = evt.target.validity.valid ? evt.target.value : number;

    setNumber(num);
  };

              <TextField
                  type="number"
                  pattern="[0-9]*"
                  variant="outlined"
                  label="Phone Number"
                  fullWidth
                  onChange={handleNumber}
                  required
                  inputProps={{
                    maxLength: 11,
                  }}
                  InputProps={{
                    disableUnderline: true,
                  }}
                />
```

**Clearing up the states:**

```
  const clearInfo = () => {
   //other fields here
    setFirstName("");
    setLastName("");
    setNumber("");
  };
```

**Submission:**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
     //codes here
      });
      updateData();
      clearInfo();  
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    setOpen(true); //for the Alert
  };
```

Update:
I tried setting up `setNumber()` and it still won't clear up

Comment: Are you using v4 or the new v5 of MUI?

Comment: Is TextField from a library or did you created that component? In any case, it's value has to be `number`. This way when you clear the number `TextField` will update accordingly.

Comment: There is no value parameter in your text field. So, setNumber has no effect on that

Comment: I am not familiar with the library, but I think you would not be able to set blank string on a type number.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am using v5

Comment: @GabrielLupu TextField is directly from the MUI

Comment: where is value props  , store your value in state , your textFieldComponent is uncontrolled , you have to control it by yourself of use formik or react hooks form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TextField` is currently [*uncontrolled*](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled) because it doesn't have a `value` property. That means when you change `number`, it has no effect on the `TextField`, because the `TextField`'s content isn't controlled by your code. To make it controlled, add `value={number}` to it. Then, `clearInfo` works correctly:

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { TextField } = MaterialUI;

const Example = () => {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState("");

    const handleNumber = (evt) => {
        const num = evt.target.validity.valid ? evt.target.value : number;
        setNumber(num);
    };

    const clearInfo = () => {
        //other fields here
        // setFirstName("");
        // setLastName("");
        setNumber("");
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            //codes here
            // updateData();
            clearInfo();  
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        // setOpen(true); //for the Alert
    };

    return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
            type="number"
            pattern="[0-9]*"
            variant="outlined"
            label="Phone Number"
            fullWidth
            onChange={handleNumber}
            value={number}
            required
            inputProps={{
                maxLength: 11,
            }}
            InputProps={{
                disableunderline: "true", // *** Changed case and value per error from React
            }}
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5.5.0/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
```

I had to make two other changes there (other than commenting out missing functions, etc.) for the snippet to work without errors:

1. I removed the `async` from `handleNumber` because it didn't have any `await` in it and unfortunately Stack Snippets using JSX don't support `async`/`await` (because they use a really old version of Babel; please vote to fix that [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386096/update-the-version-of-babel-standalone-and-others-used-by-stack-snippets)).
2. React logged a warning about `disableUnderline: true` in `InputProps` saying (in effect) to make it `disableunderline: "true"` instead, so I did that.